# Why IMultiValueConverter isn't seen in the list called 'Add value converter'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I have IValueConverter that is seen as a class in a list called 'Add value converter'.

I've created IMultivalueConverter class and it's not seen in the list at all.

Perhaps I need to perform some additional manipulation with 'Multi' to get that in the list.

Please any suggestions.

Comment: I can't understand what list you are talking about

Comment: Are you using this [IMultiValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter)?

Comment: To understand what a list is, you need to be quite familiar with Visual Studio. For example you need to bind User Control property; F4 -->Create Data binding --> Add value converter.

Comment: Yes, I have problem with IMultiValueConverter. IValueConverter is visible.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Multi Binding, There are no any syntax fails in XAML. Just can't get how Multiconverter distinguishes coming vars. Which way does it divide between value[0], value[1], value[2] For example I have three vars called A.B,C. And three values  value[0], value[1], value[2] . How it's being divided?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Data binding dialog box** is tool for working with Binding markup extension, so **Add value converter dialog box** shows only IValueConverter inheritors.

P.S. I can't find any special tools for working with MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter in Visual Studio.